# Push method replaces the last value of the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a simple Todo list app. I'm trying to use the `push` method to add to the array in JavaScript. I have a button that adds a todo and an input to enter the todo. Then an `if`/`else` statement determines whether or not the value of the todo input is `null` or an empty string. If the todo input is not `null` or an empty string then the following code is executed:

```
      todos.push(uploadTodo)
      setTodo(todos)
      console.log(todos)
```

This is where my problem is. `todos.push(uploadTodo)` will only add one new item to my array. After that it replaces the last element in the array.

Here's my code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Todo from './Todo'

function App() {
  let todos = ["Test", "testing"]
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState(todos)
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null)
 
  const getInput = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value)
  } 

  const pushTodo = (uploadTodo) => {
    if (value === null || value === "") {
      alert("Can't add an empty todo.")
    }
    else {
      todos.push(uploadTodo)
      setTodo(todos)
      console.log(todos)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Todo List!</h1>
      <Todo></Todo>
      <button onClick={() => pushTodo(value)}>Add a todo</button><button>Clear todos</button><br></br>
      <input placeholder="Add a todo" onChange={getInput}></input>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm using React 18.2.0.

Comment: Don't mutate values held in state.

Comment: use `setTodo([...todos, uploadTodo])`

Comment: @jonrshapre What does that mean? I'm open to using a better method.

Comment: @Ethan it means you cannot change an existing value. You must always create a new one. `2 + 2` is *always* equal to `4`, because 2 (and all numbers) are _immutable_ in JavaScript. Imagine you could write `(2).push(1)` and suddenly `2 + 2` suddenly equals `6`, what a nightmare that would be. React expects all stateful data to be immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time your component re-renders, your local `todos` variable gets reset to its original value by this line:

```js
let todos = ["Test", "testing"]
```

You then push the new value:

```js
todos.push(uploadTodo)
```

Now `todos` is `["Test", "Testing", uploadTodo]` and you update state:

```js
setTodo(todos)
```

This triggers a re-render, and `todos` gets reinitialized:

```
let todos = ["Test", "testing"]
```

So each time you push a value, you're pushing into the original list again.

The easiest solution is to move the `todos` value out of the component so it doesn't get reinitialized on every render:

```
const todos = ["Test", "testing"]

function App() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState(todos)
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null)
  // ...
```

But I would also strongly recommend you update state with a new array instead of continually pushing into the original `todos` one.

Calling a state update and passing in the same array that's already in state--even if the items in the array have changed--won't trigger a re-render, because React sees that the new array is the same array it already has, and this can (obviously) cause the app to behave in strange ways.

Instead of `todos.push(...)` I'd recommend you create a new array each time by spreading the existing state and appending the new value:

```js
setTodo([...todo, uploadTodo])
```

```
function App() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState(["Test", "testing"])
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null)
 
  const getInput = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value)
  } 

  const pushTodo = (uploadTodo) => {
    if (value === null || value === "") {
      alert("Can't add an empty todo.")
    }
    else {
      // create a new array with the exiting state plus the new value
      setTodo([...todo, uploadTodo])
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Todo List!</h1>
      <Todo></Todo>
      <button onClick={() => pushTodo(value)}>Add a todo</button><button>Clear todos</button><br></br>
      <input placeholder="Add a todo" onChange={getInput}></input>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to mutate the state directly by using push method instead updating the state.

Since the state is an array, you can use Array.concat method to update it:

```
setTodo(todos.concat(uploadTodo))
```

This will return a new array and set it to the state.

Updated

```
setTodo(todos.concat([uploadTodo]))
```

Comment: be careful with `.concat`. you should *always* pass an array as the argument otherwise you risk flattening the data of `uploadTodo`. `todos.concat([uploadTodo])` or `todos.concat(manyTodos)` where `manyTodos` is an array of many todos. The fail-safe approach is `[...todos, uploadTodo]`

Comment: Oh, thanks, you're right. I assumed the value was an array without properly checking the value to be concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

In React, all stateful data must be **immutable**. That means you cannot change existing values and instead you must create *new* ones. Here's a minimal, verifiable example. <kbd>Run</kbd> the example below and create a few todos. Then get to work on completing them!

You should also be aware that `setState` is **asynchronous**. This means that the value of state will not be available immediately after the `setState` call. The new state is only available during the subsequent render. Read the [Component State FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous) for details.

```js
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([])
  const [todo, setTodo] = React.useState("")
  function onChange(event) {
    setTodo(event.currentTarget.value)
  }
  function onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    setTodos([...todos, todo]) // create a *new* array!
    setTodo("")
  }
  return <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <ul>
      {todos.map((t, key) => <li key={key}>{t}</li>)}
    </ul>
    <input value={todo} onChange={onChange} placeholder="Enter a todo.." />
  </form>
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Direct way can be
setTodo([...todos, uploadTodo])

Indirect way can be
setTodo(todos.join(uploadTodo).split(""))
or
setTodo([...todos.join(uploadTodo).split("")])
as join() method does not change the original array.

Comment: It still just adds to the last element of the array.

Comment: With the original being issue was todos.push(uploadTodo) was only add one new item to my array, after that it replaces the last element in the array.With above approach new elements can be added at the end, without actually changing todos array

Comment: under no circumstances should you `join` the entire array just to re-`split` it. arrays can store elements of any type, and not all can be safely (isomorphically) converted to string and back.